# Entity Framework (Core), Unique "Composite Columns" that are not the Key

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following class

```
public Building()
{
   public int Id{Get; Set;};
   public ICollection Bars{Get; Set;};
}

public Room()
{
   public int Id{Get; Set;};

   public int BuildingId{Get; Set;};
   public Building Building{Get; Set;}; 

   public string Name{Get; Set;); 
}
```

I would like every room within a building to have a unique name. But I can't make the Name property unique, as various buildings could have the same room name

```
Room Table
Id    BuildingId    Name
1     1             Kitchen   
2     2             Kitchen    //Should be allowed as different building
3     1             Kitchen    //Should not be allowed
```

The only solution I could think of is making a composite key between BuildingId and Name.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Room>().HasKey(r=> new {r.BuildingId, r.Name});
```

Fetching rooms will happen a lot in the App, and it would be much simpler to keep the Key as a simple integer. Is there a way to make this a unique composite column without making it the key?

I believe i need something to do with Index's but I can find a working example of what im after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to use a composite key for this case, instead, you can make the combination as unique. You have to use the `HasIndex` and `IsUnique` methods like below.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Room>(b =>
            {
                b.HasIndex(e => new { e.BuildingId, e.Name}).IsUnique();
            });
```

Comment: I thought i needed an index of some sort, I didn't realise I could span an index over multiple columns. 

I will give this try tonight- Thank you

Comment: @Ben_jamin sure, let me know the status

Comment: This has fixed the problem. Exactly what was needed