# Entity Framework Core: is there a way to say an entry is unique across 2 column values?

Tags: entity-framework-core, composite-key

My question is in the context of Entity Framework Core talking to SQL database.

I have a class as follows:

```
public class County
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public State State { get; set; }
}
```

I have one of these records for each county in each state. The `Name` is not unique because there is an Orange County in both California and Florida. However, the combination of `Name + StateId` is unique.

Is there a way to specify this in Entity Framework Core so that it tells the SQL database to enforce that uniqueness? And `Id` should remain the PK so I don't want to make the `Name+StateId` a composite **primary** key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52515348/5045688

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure -

Your example is [Code First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations).

You can do something like this:

```
public class County
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_Location", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Index("IX_Location", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

"Id" remains your primary key; your table has a clustered index built on Id.  But you simply create a *second* index, for your "dual-column uniqueness constraint".  On whichever columns you want (e.g. Name + StateId).

---

Per David, here is alternative syntax, using [Fluent API/LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<County>()
    .HasIndex(e => new { e.Name, e.StateId })
    .IsUnique();
```

Comment: Thank you - that's it. Can you please add how to do this with fluent so those taking that approach have that answer. It's: modelBuilder.Entity<County>().HasIndex(e => new { e.Name, e.StateId }).IsUnique(); And then I'll accept the answer. TIA